# How to combine two Sources into new one in Crypto++?

Tags: c++, crypto++, dsa

**Situation**

I have two arbitrary sources, lets say a `StringSource` from a *signature* and a `FileSource` from the corresponding *signed file*. I now want to verify the files signature which is currently performed like this:

```
bool VerifyFile(const ECDSA<ECP, SHA512>::PublicKey &key,
                const std::string &filename,
                const std::string &signatureString) {
    std::string fileContentString;
    FileSource(filename.c_str(), true,
               new CryptoPP::StringSink(fileContentString));

    bool result = false;
    StringSource(signatureString + fileContentString, true,
                 new SignatureVerificationFilter(
                         ECDSA<ECP, SHA512>::Verifier(key),
                         new ArraySink((byte *) &result, sizeof(result))
                 ) // SignatureVerificationFilter
    );
    return result;
}
```

**My Problem**

I don't want to explicitly extract the file's content to a string, then do a concatenation and verify afterwards.

**Question**

Is there a way to pass two arbitrary sources where one represents the signature and the other one the signed content (might be a file or a string) to the verification entity?

**What I tried so far**

I tried `Source::TransferAll(...)` to a `Redirecter`, redirecting to `SignatureVerificationFilter` with no luck.

Comment: So I got to looking at the documentation and determined it pretty much sucked for this task. Doxygen was missing important information, and we did not have clear examples on the wiki. Both of them have been fixed. Also see [Commit 16768df2e51e](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/16768df2e51e), [Commit 2b4911abee7b](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/2b4911abee7b) and [Pumping Data | Multiple Sources](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pumping_Data#Multiple_Sources) on the wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two arbitrary sources, lets say a StringSource from a signature and a FileSource from the corresponding signed file. I now want to verify the files signature ...

Using multiple sources on the same filter chain can be tricky. I know the library has some baked-in classes for it but I have never liked them. They take multiple input channels and de-multiplexes them into a single channel. You can see them in action in [`test.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/test.cpp), functions `SecretRecoverFile` (around line 650) and `InformationRecoverFile` (around line 700).

---

> Is there a way to pass two arbitrary sources where one represents the signature and the other one the signed content (might be a file or a string) to the verification entity?

Here is how I would handle what you want to do. The example below uses two sources and shares a filter chain. I reduced the complexity by hashing two strings using a `HashFilter`. Your example uses message, signature, key pairs and `SignatureVerificationFilter` but it is more complex than needed to show you how to do it.

The example proceeds in four parts:

- ***Part 0*** - setup the data. Two 16K ASCII strings are created. One string is also written to a file.
- ***Part 1*** - print the data. `Hash(s1)`, `Hash(s2)` and `Hash(s1+s2)` are printed.
- ***Part 2*** - use two string sources. `Hash(s1+s2)` is created using two `StringSources`
- ***Part 3*** - use one string source and one file source. `Hash(s1+s2)` is created using one `StringSource` and one `FileSource`

To state the obvious, the simplified example calculates `Hash(s1+s2)`. In your context the operation is `Verify(key, s1+s2)`, where `key` is the public key, `s1` is the signature and `s2` is the contents of the file.

***Part 0*** - The data is setup below. It is pretty boring. Notice `s3` is a concatenation of `s1` and `s2`.

```
std::string s1, s2, s3;
const size_t size = 1024*16+1;

random_string(s1, size);
random_string(s2, size);

s3 = s1 + s2;
```

***Part 1*** - The data is printed below. The hashes of `s1`, `s2` and `s3` are printed. `s3` is the important one. `s3` is what we need to arrive at using two separate sources.

```
std::string r;
StringSource ss1(s1, true, new HashFilter(hash, new StringSink(r)));

std::cout << "s1: ";
hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
std::cout << std::endl;

r.clear();
StringSource ss2(s2, true, new HashFilter(hash, new StringSink(r)));

std::cout << "s2: ";
hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
std::cout << std::endl;

r.clear();
StringSource ss3(s3, true, new HashFilter(hash, new StringSink(r)));

std::cout << "s3: ";
hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Output looks like so:

```
$ ./test.exe
s1: 45503354F9BC56C9B5B61276375A4C60F83A2F01
s2: 6A3AD5B683DE7CA57F07E8099268A8BC80FA200B
s3: BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
...
```

***Part 2*** - This is where things get interesting. We use two different `StringSource` to process `s1` and `s2` individually.

```
StringSource ss4(s1, false);
StringSource ss5(s2, false);

HashFilter hf1(hash, new StringSink(r));

ss4.Attach(new Redirector(hf1));
ss4.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
ss4.Detach();

ss5.Attach(new Redirector(hf1));
ss5.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
ss5.Detach();

hf1.MessageEnd();

std::cout << "s1 + s2: ";
hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
std::cout << std::endl;
```

It produces the following output:

```
$ ./test.exe
s1: 45503354F9BC56C9B5B61276375A4C60F83A2F01
s2: 6A3AD5B683DE7CA57F07E8099268A8BC80FA200B
s3: BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
s1 + s2: BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
...
```

There are several things going on in the code above. First, we dynamically attach and detach the hash filter chain to sources `ss4` and `ss5`.

Second, once the filter is attached we use `Pump(LWORD_MAX)` to pump all the data from the source into the filter chain. We don't use `PumpAll()` because `PumpAll()` signals the end of the current message and generates a `MessageEnd()`. We are processing one message in multiple parts; we are not processing multiple messages. So we want only one `MessageEnd()` when we determine.

Third, once we are done with the source, we call `Detach` so `StringSource` destructors *don't* cause a spurious `MessageEnd()` message to enter the filter chain. Again, we are processing one message in multiple parts; we are not processing multiple messages. So we want only one `MessageEnd()` when we determine.

Fourth, when we are done sending our data into the filter, we call `hf.MessageEnd()` to tell the filter to process all pending or buffered data. This is when we want the `MessageEnd()` call, and not before.

Fifth, we call `Detach()` when done rather than `Attach()`. `Detach()` deletes the existing filter chain and avoids memory leaks. `Attach()` attaches a new chain but does *not* delete the existing filter or chain. Since we are using a `Redirector` our `HashFilter` survives. The `HashFilter` is eventually cleaned as an automatic stack variable.

As an aside, if `ss4.PumpAll()` and `ss5.PumpAll()` were used (or allowed destructors to send `MessageEnd()` into the filter chain) then you would get a concatenation of `Hash(s1)` and `Hash(s2)` because it would look like two different messages to the filter instead of one message over two parts. The code below is wrong:

```
StringSource ss4(s1, false);
StringSource ss5(s2, false);

HashFilter hf1(hash, new StringSink(r));

ss4.Attach(new Redirector(hf1));
// ss4.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
ss4.PumpAll();  // MessageEnd
ss4.Detach();

ss5.Attach(new Redirector(hf1));
// ss5.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
ss5.PumpAll();  // MessageEnd
ss5.Detach();

// Third MessageEnd
hf1.MessageEnd();
```

The incorrect code above produces `Hash(s1) || Hash(s2) || Hash(<empty string>)`:

```
$ ./test.exe
s1: 45503354F9BC56C9B5B61276375A4C60F83A2F01
s2: 6A3AD5B683DE7CA57F07E8099268A8BC80FA200B
s3: BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
s1 + s2: 45503354F9BC56C9B5B61276375A4C60F83A2F016A3AD5B683DE7CA57F07E8099268A8BC80FA200BDA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709
```

***Part 3*** - This is your use case. We use a `StringSource` and `FileSource` to process `s1` and `s2` individually. Remember, the string `s2` was written to a file named `test.dat`.

```
StringSource ss6(s1, false);
FileSource fs1("test.dat", false);

HashFilter hf2(hash, new StringSink(r));

ss6.Attach(new Redirector(hf2));
ss6.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
ss6.Detach();

fs1.Attach(new Redirector(hf2));
fs1.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
fs1.Detach();

hf2.MessageEnd();

std::cout << "s1 + s2 (file): ";
hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Here is what running the full example looks like:

```
$ ./test.exe
s1: 45503354F9BC56C9B5B61276375A4C60F83A2F01
s2: 6A3AD5B683DE7CA57F07E8099268A8BC80FA200B
s3: BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
s1 + s2: BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
s1 + s2 (file): BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
```

Notice `s3` = `s1 + s2` = `s1 + s2 (file)`.

---

```
$ cat test.cxx

#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "sha.h"
#include "hex.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void random_string(std::string& str, size_t len)
{
    const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const size_t size = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;

    str.reserve(len);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        str.push_back(alphanum[rand() % size]);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    ////////////////////////// Part 0 //////////////////////////

    // Deterministic
    std::srand(0);

    std::string s1, s2, s3, r;
    const size_t size = 1024*16+1;

    random_string(s1, size);
    random_string(s2, size);

    // Concatenate for verification
    s3 = s1 + s2;

    // Write s2 to file
    StringSource(s2, true, new FileSink("test.dat"));

    // Hashing, resets after use
    SHA1 hash;

    // Printing hex encoded string to std::cout
    HexEncoder hex(new FileSink(std::cout));

    ////////////////////////// Part 1 //////////////////////////

    r.clear();
    StringSource ss1(s1, true, new HashFilter(hash, new StringSink(r)));

    std::cout << "s1: ";
    hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    r.clear();
    StringSource ss2(s2, true, new HashFilter(hash, new StringSink(r)));

    std::cout << "s2: ";
    hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    r.clear();
    StringSource ss3(s3, true, new HashFilter(hash, new StringSink(r)));

    std::cout << "s3: ";
    hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    ////////////////////////// Part 2 //////////////////////////

    r.clear();
    StringSource ss4(s1, false);
    StringSource ss5(s2, false);

    HashFilter hf1(hash, new StringSink(r));

    ss4.Attach(new Redirector(hf1));
    ss4.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
    ss4.Detach();

    ss5.Attach(new Redirector(hf1));
    ss5.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
    ss5.Detach();

    hf1.MessageEnd();

    std::cout << "s1 + s2: ";
    hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    ////////////////////////// Part 3 //////////////////////////

    r.clear();
    StringSource ss6(s1, false);
    FileSource fs1("test.dat", false);

    HashFilter hf2(hash, new StringSink(r));

    ss6.Attach(new Redirector(hf2));
    ss6.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
    ss6.Detach();

    fs1.Attach(new Redirector(hf2));
    fs1.Pump(LWORD_MAX);
    fs1.Detach();

    hf2.MessageEnd();

    std::cout << "s1 + s2 (file): ";
    hex.Put((const byte*)r.data(), r.size());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
$ g++ test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
$ ./test.exe
s1: 45503354F9BC56C9B5B61276375A4C60F83A2F01
s2: 6A3AD5B683DE7CA57F07E8099268A8BC80FA200B
s3: BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
s1 + s2: BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
s1 + s2 (file): BFC1882CEB24697A2B34D7CF8B95604B7109F28D
```

---

Here's a class that may ease your pain. It brings together the concepts above in a `MultipleSources` class. `MultipleSources` is only a partial implementation of the `Source` interface, but it should have all the pieces you need.

```
class MultipleSources
{
public:
    MultipleSources(std::vector<Source*>& source, Filter& filter)
    : m_s(source), m_f(filter)
    {
    }

    void Pump(lword pumpMax, bool messageEnd)
    {
        for (size_t i=0; pumpMax && i<m_s.size(); ++i)
        {
            lword n = pumpMax;
            m_s[i]->Attach(new Redirector(m_f));            
            m_s[i]->Pump2(n);
            m_s[i]->Detach();
            pumpMax -= n;
        }

        if (messageEnd)
            m_f.MessageEnd();
    }

    void PumpAll()
    {
        for (size_t i=0; i<m_s.size(); ++i)
        {
            m_s[i]->Attach(new Redirector(m_f));
            m_s[i]->Pump(LWORD_MAX);
            m_s[i]->Detach();
        }

        m_f.MessageEnd();
    }

private:
    std::vector<Source*>& m_s;
    Filter &m_f;
};
```

You would call it like so:

```
StringSource ss(s1, false);
FileSource fs("test.dat", false);
HashFilter hf(hash, new StringSink(r));

std::vector<Source*> srcs;
srcs.push_back(&ss);
srcs.push_back(&fs);

MultipleSources ms(srcs, hf);
ms.Pump(LWORD_MAX, false);

hf.MessageEnd();
```

Or you can use `PumpAll` and get the same result, but you don't call `hf.MessageEnd();` in this case because `PumpAll` signals the end of the message.

```
MultipleSources ms(srcs, hf);
ms.PumpAll();
```

Comment: amazing work! I think this perfectly answers my question... Thank you very much